# Why R does not recognize special characters from an imported MySQL table?

Tags: sql, mysql, r, dataframe

I have this character vector called "my_files2" (chr [1:6]) that contains these 6 characters:

```
 "#KızılcıkŞerbeti", "#zorunlucoğrafyadersi", "Jüpiter", "Ömer 
  Çelik", "Tanju Özcan" , "Carola"
```

And I have this dataframe called "trends" (dataframe) with two columns "trend" (character) and "Date" (POSIXct).

| trend | Date |
| --- | --- |
| #KızılcıkŞerbeti | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| #zorunlucoğrafyadersi | 2022-12-01 12:59 |
| Ömer Çelik | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| Jüpiter | 2022-12-01 12:54 |
| Tanju Özcan | 2022-12-01 12:57 |
| Ferrari | 2022-12-01 12:54 |
| Edip | 2022-12-01 12:57 |
| Carola | 2022-12-01 12:54 |
| Felix | 2022-12-01 12:53 |

This dataframe comes from a SQL-format dump file that was imported into 'MySQLWorkbench' and subsequently into Rstudio via the packages 'RMySQL' and 'DBI'.

The problem is that when I try to 'filter' the dataframe considering only the words in my_files2, it only recognizes the word 'Carola' and not the others.  I thought it might be a encoding problem since these words contain umlauts and other special symbols. Would you know how to solve the problem?

My code so far (I want to create a dataframe "trends_2" that contains only the words in the vector:

```
  if (!require(RMySQL)) {
  install.packages(RMySQL)
   }
  if (!require(DBI)) {
  install.packages(DBI)
  }

  # Connection with MySQL server

  mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', 
  password='***', dbname='Trends_data', host='localhost')

  rsN = dbSendQuery(mydb, 'set character set "utf8"') 

  # Select table from database 'Trends_data'

  rs1 = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * FROM trends") 
  trends= dbFetch(rs1, n=-1)
  dbClearResult(rs1)

                
   trends_2 <- trends%>% filter(trend %in% myfiles_2 )
```

Comment: Please post fuller code than a single line snippet. We need to see actual definition of `trends` and `myfiles_2`

Comment: I modified the question with more details

Comment: Try printing out the distict values of `trends$trend` and compare with `myfiles_2`. Also, I see you print out values but can you really show how `myfiles_2` is defined? From CSV with proper encoding?